# Conditionally Remove Row in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

My data looks like this:

| year | country | leader | valuex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1978 | A | X | 0 |
| 1979 | A | X | 1 |
| 1980 | A | T | 1 |
| 1981 | A | T | 0 |
| 1956 | B | Y | 2 |
| 1957 | B | Y | 1 |
| 1958 | B | Y | 0 |
| 1959 | B | M | 0 |
| 1995 | C | Z | 0 |

I want to drop rows who have value zero but if I have only one observation like in the C, I want to keep them. As such my data looks like this:

| year | country | leader | valuex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1979 | A | X | 1 |
| 1980 | A | T | 1 |
| 1956 | B | Y | 2 |
| 1957 | B | Y | 1 |
| 1959 | B | M | 0 |
| 1995 | C | Z | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(country, leader) %>%
  filter(n() == 1L | valuex != 0) %>%
  ungroup()
# . + # A tibble: 6 x 4
#    year country leader valuex
#   <int> <chr>   <chr>   <int>
# 1  1979 A       X           1
# 2  1980 A       T           1
# 3  1956 B       Y           2
# 4  1957 B       Y           1
# 5  1959 B       M           0
# 6  1995 C       Z           0
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(year = c(1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1956L, 1957L, 1958L, 1959L, 1995L), country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"), leader = c("X", "X", "T", "T", "Y", "Y", "Y", "M", "Z"), valuex = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I have edited data because I could explain my data structure in a bad way. Also, I have tried that one: library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(country, leader) %>%
  filter(n() == 1L | valuex != 0) %>%
  ungroup()  but  it does not work. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: You never mentioned grouping by `leader`. All I did was add that to `group_by` and it works, otherwise unmodified.

Comment: I am so sorry @r2evans. You are completely right.